# What is the appropriate virtual host for this apache2.4 and laravel setup?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, vhosts

I have an internal site I call `eaglets`. I use it to host a bunch of javascript calculators and such. I want to use a laravel app and have the address look like `http://eaglets/playground`.

I have the playground folder in my `var/www/html` directory, which is my default document root.

If I put a dummy `index.html` in my `var/www/html/playground/` folder and go `http://eaglets/playground`, it comes up fine. This leads me to believe my vhost is not pointing correctly to the `var/www/html/playground/public` folder.

This is my virtual host file:

```
  1 <VirtualHost *:80>
  2
  3         ServerName eaglets/playground
  4         ServerAlias eaglets/playground
  5         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/playground/public
  6         <Directory /var/www/html/playground/public>
  7                 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  8                 AllowOverride All
  9                 Require all granted
 10         </Directory>
 11
 12         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/playground-error.log
 13         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/playground-access.log combined
 14
 15 </VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

If I do apachectl -S I get:

```
    VirtualHost configuration:
*:80 is a NameVirtualHost
default server eaglets (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost eaglets (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost eaglets/playground (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/playground.conf:1)
alias eaglets/playground
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same usecase and here is config(names&paths changed to yours):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName eaglets
    Alias /playground /var/www/html/playground/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/playground/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```